# Laravel sql query model relations

Tags: laravel

Assume a following example:

I got table of cars, their owners and a table of their types.

**table cars**:
id, owner_id, type_id

**table types**:
name, description

I want to get all types, whose id is NOT in type_id in table cars AND their owner_id IS 1.

I pass owner from the view and I tried the following:

```
public function show(Owner $owner)
    {

        $cartypes =CarTypes::all()->whereNotIn('id', function($query) { $query->table('cars')->select('type_id')->where('owner_id', '=', $owner->id); })->get();



        return view('sections.cars.show',compact('owner','cartypes'));


    }
```

But get Error: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table does not exist.

Is my query fine? Can someone help me fix my query to get desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `whereDoesntHave` to get all types which are not in cars table where owner id is 1

```
$owner_id = 1;

CarTypes::whereDoesntHave('cars', function ($query) use ($owner_id) {
    $query->where('owner_id', '=', $owner_id );
})->get();
```

[Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Make sure your `CarTypes` model has mappings for cars

```
public function cars(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cars', 'type_id');
}
```

Comment: You are my hero.